# Trying to parse with Jquery.parseJson... part II

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I have recently post here about the Jquery.parseJson. Now I'm in part II of my achievement. I got this script working with a stackoverflow user help.

```
<input type="text" id="query" /><button>search</button><br />
<div id="results">

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            $("#query").val(); // Do nothing with this value
            var json = eval('({"name":"John"})');
            $("#results").append('<p>' + json.name + '</p>');
            // $.getJSON('{"name":"John"}',function(json){
            //     $.each(json.results,function(i,obj){
            //         $("#results").append('<p>' + obj.name + '</p>');
            //     });
            // });
        });
    });
```

Now that I have this code working I have build a real JSON to parse, here it is:

```
["http:\/\/guimaraes-braga.olx.pt\/seat-leon-1-9tdi-sport-111cv-iid-148286318",
 {"1":"http:\/\/static04.olx-st.com\/images\/v4\/logos\/logo-default.png"},
     {"2":"http:\/\/images03.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292857323_148286318_1.jpg"},
 {"3":"http:\/\/images04.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_2.jpg"},
        {"4":"http:\/\/images04.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_3.jpg"},
 {"5":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_4.jpg"},
 {"6":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_5.jpg"},
 {"7":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_6.jpg"},
 {"8":"http:\/\/images03.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292857323_148286318_1.jpg"},
 {"9":"http:\/\/images04.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_2.jpg"},
 {"10":"http:\/\/images04.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_3.jpg"},
 {"11":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_4.jpg"},
 {"12":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_5.jpg"},
 {"13":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_6.jpg"},
 {"14":"http:\/\/images01.olx.com\/images\/spinner.gif"},
 {"15":"http:\/\/images01.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/1292886514_148286318_1-Fotos-de--SEAT-LEON-19TDI-SPORT-111CV.jpg"},
 {"16":""}]
```

This JSON above contain the URLs for images, and I have tried to pass this JSON just like in the first script, but it is not working... some more details in the code below.

```
<?php $json = new img_json_output(); ?>
<?php $data = $json->get_img_tags_as_json($json->get_page('http://guimaraes-braga.olx.pt/seat-leon-1-9tdi-sport-111cv-iid-148286318')); ?>

<input type="text" id="query" /><button>search</button><br />
<div id="results">

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            $("#query").val(); // Do nothing with this value
            var json = eval(<?php echo $data; ?>);
            $("#results").append('<p>' + json.1 + '</p>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The PHP variable $data returns the JSON.

How to get this to work? Is the problem on my JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to your question but just a suggestion.  Have you tried out the json2 library?  It is really good and handles parsing and serializing json.  Here is a link  [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html).  When minified it is 2.5k so not much additional overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var json = eval( "(" + '<?php echo $data; ?>' + ")" );
```

Try to check:
1. the JSON string doesn't contain carriage returns.
2. the method chain. The outermost structure is an Array. It should be json[0] or json[1]["1"].

The following script works for me.

```
 <body>
     <input type="text" id="query" /><button>search</button><br />
     <div id="results">

     </div>

     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('button').click(function(){
                 var json = eval('(' + '["http:\/\/guimaraes-braga.olx.pt\/seat-leon-1-9tdi-sport-111cv-iid-148286318", {"1":"http:\/\/static04.olx-st.com\/images\/v4\/logos\/logo-default.png"}, {"2":"http:\/\/images03.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292857323_148286318_1.jpg"}, {"3":"http:\/\/images04.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_2.jpg"}, {"4":"http:\/\/images04.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_3.jpg"}, {"5":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_4.jpg"}, {"6":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_5.jpg"}, {"7":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_6.jpg"}, {"8":"http:\/\/images03.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292857323_148286318_1.jpg"}, {"9":"http:\/\/images04.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_2.jpg"}, {"10":"http:\/\/images04.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_3.jpg"}, {"11":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_4.jpg"}, {"12":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_5.jpg"}, {"13":"http:\/\/images02.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/t_1292886514_148286318_6.jpg"}, {"14":"http:\/\/images01.olx.com\/images\/spinner.gif"}, {"15":"http:\/\/images01.olx.pt\/ui\/10\/71\/18\/1292886514_148286318_1-Fotos-de--SEAT-LEON-19TDI-SPORT-111CV.jpg"}, {"16":""}]' + ')');
                 for (var i=1; i<json.length; i++){
                     $("#results").append('<p>' + json[i][i] + '</p>');
                 }
             });
         });
     </script>
    <hr />
 </body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But it is not working. Maybe the JSON that not is generated in the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = eval(<?php echo $data; ?>); // Will not work
```

Get rid of the eval function. JSON is valid JavaScript in this context of assigning it to a variable from server-generated JavaScript code. Then it should work fine:

```
var json = <?php echo $data; ?>; // Works fine
```

You do need to fix this line though:

```
$("#results").append('<p>' + json.1 + '</p>');
```

Try something like `json[1]["1"]` instead of `json.1`.